# How to dynamically add textboxes and label in flowlayoutpanel and store them in database?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making rhythm register and I am using Flowlayoutpanel.
What I want to do is to create dynamically labels and Textboxes as many as user wants. 
User will enter his/her Task as shown in figure then it will tell the goal in numbers.

For example reading pages of book. The goal will divide into 7 days. The textbox in front of `Actual=Goal/7`.
The Textbox in front of Done will show the user input what user did that day.
The problem I am facing here is that how can I create another FlowLayout panel with the same Textboxes and labels as shown in figure to show more than one task of users.

Furthermore I'm interested in storing them to a database.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you want to A) dynamically create Textboxes as many as user wants and B) you want to store **Textboxes** in the database, you might want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 1):

Combine labels and textboxes that form an ensemble into one UserControl. The UserControl designer works like the Form designer. You can place controls on it, you can create event handlers and add properties to make the values of the controls accessible publicly.

I would store the controls you add to the flowLayoutPanel1 in a list as well; this makes it easier to access them from code and to store the corresponding values in a database.

```
private List<TaskUserControl> _tasks = new List<TaskUserControl>();

private void AddTask()
{
    var task = new TaskUserControl();
    _tasks.Add(task);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(task);
}
```

---

[How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (msdn)
[How to add a new row to an existing table using c# sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1791042/880990) (stackoverflow)