# Insert a dataSet into a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have a dataset filled up with data from  3 different table. I want to store that dataset in an empty table in SQL, i have already created the table.

```
public void SaveDataBaseTailleALL(DataGridView dataGridViewRALSelectedTaille, DataSet oDSALL)
{
    PointageCls.totalPointage(dataGridViewRALSelectedTaille);
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=HOOSSEN-HP\\INFO2;Initial Catalog=SuiviOF;User ID=sa;Password= PROTECTED;"
    //string strSQL = ")";

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblTailleALL)", cn);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt);
    adapt.update(oDSALL.Tables[0]);
    oDSALL.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
}
```

What should I do to achieve saving the dataset in an empty table ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can Refer Following code:

```
public static OleDbDataAdapter CreateCustomerAdapter(
    OleDbConnection connection)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand command;

    // Create the SelectCommand.
    command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers " +
        "WHERE Country = ? AND City = ?", connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("Country", OleDbType.VarChar, 15);
    command.Parameters.Add("City", OleDbType.VarChar, 15);

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    // Create the InsertCommand.
    command = new OleDbCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?)", connection);

    command.Parameters.Add(
        "CustomerID", OleDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add(
        "CompanyName", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "CompanyName");

    adapter.InsertCommand = command;
    return adapter;
}
```

Its OLEDB , but syntaxwise you can convert it in sql.

**Doccumental Referance:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: I have a DataSet filled up by 3 tables. I have selected data from 3 different tables and add them to my dataSet. Now I want to save that dataSet in an empty table in sql. I have already created the table ...  Thanks

Comment: @user2967732 in your query you mentioned only 1 : select * from tblTailleALL

Comment: This is a method. I have passed a DataSet in my method. I wanted to update my empty table with the data in the data set. But the error is that since the table is empty i cannot update. I will get Concurrency error.

Comment: @user2967732  well in case of multiple tables , you need to create datarows as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791042/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-an-existing-table-using-c-sharp-sql-server?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Create a User-Defined TableType in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableType] AS TABLE(
[UserId] int NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[Password] [varchar](30)
```

)

and define a parameter in your Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTable]
@myTableType TableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
insert into [dbo].Users select * from @myTableType 
END
```

and send your DataTable directly to sql server:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertTable");
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 var dt = new DataTable(); //create your own data table
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myTableType", dt));
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I have to convert my dataset in a data table . So, i should do that. DataTable dt = MyDataSet.Tables[0];


Well, I really appreciate, This does get me in the right way! Thanks for your kind and well step wise answer.

Comment: i have not yet implemented your solution, Once i do it i will give you a feedback .

Comment: I have created my table already in SQL. I just need to store the dataset data into that table. My table name is tblTailleALL.

Comment: please provide some extra detail I can't understand what you want